# how to display picture from api using plain javascript

Tags: javascript, api

So i am using an external api to populate html with data. I have everything except the picture. photo.innerHTML is not going to work. I just gave that a shot anyway. Then i tried photo.src but for some reason the photo cannot be found. Anyone have any ideas?

```
const genButton = document.getElementById('btn');

const photo = document.getElementById('photo');
const firstName = document.getElementById('first');
const lastName = document.getElementById('last');
const street = document.getElementById('street');
const phone = document.getElementById('phone');
const email = document.getElementById('email');

function getData() {
  const xml = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xml.open('GET', 'https://randomuser.me/api', true);

  xml.onload = function () {
    if (this.status === 200) {
      const response = JSON.parse(this.response);
      console.log(response)

     let output = "";
     let output = `
      <img src=${response.results[0].picture.large} class="card-img-top" alt="im fred" id="photo"> 
      </img>`;

      photo.src = output

      photo.innerHTML = response.results[0].picture.large;
      firstName.innerHTML = response.results[0].name.first;
      lastName.innerHTML = response.results[0].name.last;
      street.innerHTML = response.results[0].location.street.name;
      phone.innerHTML = response.results[0].phone;
      email.innerHTML = response.results[0].email;

    };
  };
  xml.send()

}

genButton.addEventListener("click", getData)
```

Comment: aren't you just missing the quotation marks around the image src attribute value?

Comment: Why are you setting the `src` attribute to that HTML string?

Comment: You can't use `document.getElementById('photo')` before you create that element and insert it into the dom

Answer (score 1):

you are just missing the quotation marks around the image src:

```js
 let output = `<img src="${response.results[0].picture.large}" class="card-img-top" alt="im fred" id="photo"></img>`;
```

Answer (score 0):

So after so much experimentation and tutorials. I got it to work. The picture shows up.
instead of innerHTML i used src which is the source of the img tag. I dont know how i did not realize this earlier. This worked for me.

```
photo.src = response.results[0].picture.large
```